# poly2nb {spdep} not identifying neighbours correctly

Tags: r, autocorrelation, spdep

I am trying to do some spatial generalised linear mixed models for areal unit data with the CARBayes package. As part of this, I need to identify the polygon neighbours into a neighbour list using `spdep::poly2nb`.

The shapefile I have of NSW is located here: [Dropbox with shapefile](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6eonesamqq3h8ru/AADSNSbISw09v6iuC2h-rQgVa?dl=0)

There is a freely available Australia wide version at: [ABS.gov.au](https://www.abs.gov.au/AUSSTATS/abs@.nsf/DetailsPage/1270.0.55.003July%202016?OpenDocument) but I'm only after NSW.

```
library(spdep)
library(sf)
library(sp)
library(lwgeom)

p <- read_sf("NSW_POA_arc.shp")

p.nb <- poly2nb(p)

coords <- st_coordinates(st_centroid(st_geometry(p))) # this seems to miss some polygons

plot(st_geometry(p), border="grey")
plot(p.nb, coords, pch = 19, cex = 0.4, add=TRUE)
```

[image]

For some reason `poly2nb` isn't recognising that some of the polygons are neighbours to each other. I've tried using the `snap` feature but this only vaguely works at `snap = 0.0001`. It also adds connections to non-neighbours.

```
xx <- poly2nb(p, snap = 0.0001)
plot(st_geometry(p), border="grey")
plot(xx, coords, pch = 19, cex = 0.4, add=TRUE)
```

[image]

I'm not sure if its a topology issue but `lwgeom::st_is_valid` says that the polygons are valid.

Any ideas would be amazing. I'm very new to writting these questions properly so any feedback is welcome. 
Many thanks

Comment: apart from `Library` instead of `library` this is a perfectly well-written question. Clear statement, given the data and code so we can reproduce it. I subsetted it down to three of the top left regions and despite the `st_distance` being zero they still don't show up as connected in `poly2nb`... working on it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I thought `poly2nb` used the "overlaps" test for determining adjacency, I do get a different set of adjacencies if I explicitly use `st_overlaps` and build an `nb` object. This looks closer to the correct form of adjacency.

```
 nsw = st_read("./NSW_POA_arc.shp",quiet=TRUE)
 overlapmat = st_overlaps(nsw,sparse=FALSE)
 ## although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_overlaps assumes that they are 
 ## planar
 ovnb = mat2listw(overlapmat)
 plot(nsw$geom);plot(ovnb, st_coordinates(st_centroid(nsw)),add=TRUE)
```

Produces:

[image]

Note this is a `listw` object, but the `$neighbours` element is a `nb` object.

There's some difference between this and your "extra tolerance" version:

```
> ovnb$neighbours
Neighbour list object:
Number of regions: 622 
Number of nonzero links: 3240 
Percentage nonzero weights: 0.8374603 
Average number of links: 5.209003 
1 region with no links:
132
> nbsnap <- poly2nb(nsw, snap = 0.0001)
> nbsnap
Neighbour list object:
Number of regions: 622 
Number of nonzero links: 3260 
Percentage nonzero weights: 0.8426298 
Average number of links: 5.241158 
1 region with no links:
132
```

For example the second region has two more neighbours in the extra tolerance version than in the overlaps version:

```
> ovnb$neighbours[[2]]
[1]  99 155 159 160
> nbsnap[[2]]
[1]  74  94  99 155 159 160
```

[image]

Here region 2 is in yellow, the four greenish ones are the "overlaps" regions, the two blueish ones are the additional ones found by increasing the tolerance.

I don't see any evidence of the increased snap tolerance adding neighbours where there's no close connection, except as above where it has added a connection where there seems to be a single point common to the yellow and one of the blueish polygons.

Another approach to adjacency is to compute `st_distance` and apply a near-zero cutoff. This should work well and is flexible enough that you can increase the tolerance enough to jump over digitising errors or very small gaps caused by narrow rivers between regions.

Comment: Hi @Spacedman, thank you for your answer. Do you know of a way to individually assign neighbours to a neighbour list? If that is possible to upload a csv or similar with them pre-populated? If both of those are possible is there a way to have the map interactive with labels (leaflet?) and then populate the list from there. Or is all of that a bit much because it won't affect the CARBayes calculations.

Comment: Yes, there's a whole bunch of functions in `spdep` for converting, creating, and modifying `listw` and `nb` objects, including an interactive (but clunky) `edit` function. Underneath it all an `nb` is a list and you can mostly treat it as such by setting elements with `mynb[[3]]=c(4,5,7)`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll give that a go and see how I go.